# what is the best way to decompose spark transformation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark application that applied many transformations on many files
firstly I created one transformation (many data Frames that carry out those transformation ) an a single action (persistence the result, about 1M row), however, this version doesn't work it always throws CG, or heap Exceptions, therefore, I decompose it to intermediate actions, and I persist every intermediate result, At first I thought that having many read/write operations will have performance issue however it works, so my question is:

what is the best way to decompose spark transformation (I think that reading/writing operations are not optimal)?

Answer (score 1):

IO is slower than simple computation, but extremely complex computation may be slower than IO. Cache is limited and need to be used to reduce compute time.

I would cache the extremely complex computation so that they won't be reevaluated multiple times. If the data is used more than twice then it breaks even the IO time.

If the computation is not that complex then you needn't cache and just recompute. But see how many times its being reused, if reuse is high then cache yields better performance.

There are various storage options (memory, Disk, both) to cache intermediate data, you can leverage that instead of writing them explicitly to disk.